# Joining table into 4 columns and show another fields

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I have a new problem, as information from my question before, I already successfully show 4 column from joining another table, but I got another problem to show another column, for more detail :

Table personal (tbl_personal)

```
+---+-----+------------+
|ID |Name |Skill       |
+---+-----+------------+
| 1 | Nia | Accountant |
| 2 | Tia | Banking    |
| 3 | Ria | Technicall |
| 4 | Dia | Admin      |
+---+-----+------------+
```

Table master (tbl_master)

```
+---+---------+---------+-----------+--------+----+
|ID |Employee1|Employee2|Departement|Division|Note|
+---+---------+---------+-----------+--------+----+
| 1 | 1       | 2       | MSO       | MWS    | etc|
| 2 | 2       | 1       | DSO       | SE     | etc|
| 3 | 3       | 4       | OSO       | GA     | etc|
+---+---------+---------+-----------+--------+----+
```

I want to show into web page from tbl_master above in codeigniter like this :

```
+---+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+-----------+--------+----+
|ID |Name 1 |Skill 1    |Name 2 |Skill 2    |Departement|Division|Note|
+---+-------+-----------+-------+-----------+-----------+--------+----+
| 1 | Nia   | Accountant| Tia   | Banking   | MSO       | MWS    | etc|
| 2 | Tia   | Banking   | Nia   | Accountant| DSO       | SE     | etc|
| 3 | Ria   | Technicall| Dia   | Admin     | OSO       | GA     | etc|
+---+---------+---------+-------+-----------+-----------+--------+----+
```

I already got solution to show Name 1, Skill 1 until Skill 2 with this code :

```
select tp1.name name1,tp1.skill skill1,tp2.name name2,tp2.skill skill2 
from tbl_master tm
join tbl_personal tp1
on tm.Employee1 =tp1.ID
join tbl_personal tp2
on tm.Employee2 =tp2.ID
```

but I have another problem to show departemen, Division, and Note columns, if there any advice, please, thanks...

Comment: ohh really @karisma  r u novice in SQL ?

Comment: you just need to add tm.depaertment and so on

Comment: ok thanks bro, sorry i very new (:

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change your select and add those columns:

```
select tp1.name name1,tp1.skill skill1,tp2.name name2,tp2.skill skill2,tm.Departement, tm.Division, tm.Note
from tbl_master tm
join tbl_personal tp1
on tm.Employee1 =tp1.ID
join tbl_personal tp2
on tm.Employee2 =tp2.ID
```